# C# Как вытащить только цифры в int из string?

Tags: c#

C# Как вытащить только цифры в `int` из `string` ?

- Даже если там сборная солянка типа `"текст: текст - 500 текст"` на выходе `500`
- И если между цифрами есть пробел, соединить их `"текст 1 500 текст"` на выходе `1500`

До этого долго разбирался как вытащить из `"500 текст"` `500`

```
int val = int.Parse(s.Split(' ')[0]);
```

А как из сборной солянки вытягивать, вообще не пойму

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string a = "aaa123bbb";
int value;
int.TryParse(string.Join("", a.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c))), out value);
```

Comment: Здорово ! Спасибо что не прошли мимо.

Comment: @Vipz На здоровье. Успехов.

Answer (score 3):

Еще вариант через регулярные выражения:

```
int result;
string resultString = string.Join(string.Empty, Regex.Matches("текст: текст - 1 500 текст", @"\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));
int.TryParse(resultString, out result);
```